# Taiwan quarantine?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, taiwan, quarantine

There is an announcement that there is 3 days quarantine rule which should be in specific hotel and taxi from airport. My destination is Tainan but I reach to taipei airport. Where should I go to quarantine? Taipei or Tainan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Taiwan CDC](https://www.cdc.gov.tw/En/Category/QAPage/SbkmnM5v0OwdDMjJ2tI_xw):

> arriving travelers shall also provide proof of the place of quarantine where travelers stay to undergo quarantine  (in principle, the place of quarantine shall be a quarantine hotel or a group quarantine facility where they plan to stay at their own expense); they should take quarantine taxis at their own expense or get a ride from their friends, relatives, companies, or organizations to go to quarantine hotels or group quarantine facilities after arrival.

So you can quarantine anywhere, *but* you need to use a dedicated transport to get there, you can't use public transport.  This either means arranging some sort of charter ride to Tainan, which will obviously be expensive since it's literally at the other end of the island, or quarantining in/near Taipei.

Have you considered flying into Kaohsiung?  It would be much closer to Tainan.

Comment: Thanks. Since we are going from europe I think that airport would not be possible for us. So any case we should quarantine in Taipei. I hope these rules are released until first of august

Comment: @AhmadTurani Vietnam Airlines appears to fly Hanoi-Kaohsiung daily, so connecting to that would be one option.  More ideas here: https://www.flightconnections.com/flights-from-kaohsiung-khh

Comment: Also, please accept (click tick mark) the answer if it works for you!

Comment: sure. If you are in Taiwan how is it going regarding the rules? o you think it is going to be realesed?

Comment: I get my Taiwan gossip in English from http://www.taiwannews.com.tw/  They have articles on proposed future quarantine arrangements.

Comment: ..And many flights from Hong Kong to Kaohsiung (about an hour). Make sure you have your intended address in Chinese to put on your form.